# How to recover the attribute table data

Tags: layers, attribute-table, fields-attributes

[image]

[image]

I downloaded a new shapefile and is displayed without any value in the attribute table, do you know what could be the reason?

Comment: Did you download a zip file with .shp,.shx, and .dbf files with the same prefix, or just a .shp? Did you rename any files? Generally, a missing .dbf should mean that the dataset won't draw, because it is corrupt.

Comment: yes, I have it all files.......... I think one of those files I rename, what shall I do?

Comment: Well, *un*-rename it, to start.

Comment: Also your image for protected area show 0 feature so an empty attribute table is normal (having 0 feature in the dataset could be normal or could be caused by any renaming and/or missing file, corrupt download...)